# HTML code to give heading names to table having <th colpsan=2></th>

Tags: html

I want to implement something like this as attached in the image file... In HTML code..

Can anyone please help..

[Table-Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdrLR.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? What have you searched? Show your code. Stack overflow is not a free coding place.

See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn from learning sites like [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Here is the HTML for a table with colspan:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>Sl</td>
    <td colspan="2">val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```